# Export Hausman test

Tags: stata, export-to-word

I am searching for a way to export my Hausman test in Stata
(`hausman model1 model2`)
Can someone help me with that?

Optionally I am open to any other suggestions on how to report findings of conducted Hausman tests in Stata for my paper.
I think when I report having conducted it, I need to append the results (correct me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: I think it would depend on what kind of paper this is and what you mean by "report". Generally these types of tests are relegated to a p-value in a footnote, but if this is a school project you might have to give more. I don't know of a way to export `hausman` results directly, but someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In the case of the latter I would tend to "copy as table" from the results window and paste into excel and call it a day.

Comment: thank you again, JR96! It's actually for school so my lecturer gets the do-file anyway. I think I might do it with the footnote, ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by exporting (exporting to Excel, exporting to a table, etc...)?

In any case, from `help hausman`:

```
hausman stores the following in r():

Scalars   
  r(chi2)        chi-squared
  r(df)          degrees of freedom for the statistic
  r(p)           p-value for the chi-squared
  r(rank)        rank of (V_b-V_B)^(-1)
```

So these are the results you can access after running `hausman`. For example:

```
hausman model1 model2
scalar chi2 = r(chi2)
```

The above code stores the chi-square in a scalar. You can then use this scalar to export it the way you want.

Comment: ah, thank you! Yes, actually I was not very specific, I am sorry, but ```scalar chi2 = r(chi2) ``` helped me as I decided I might not want to actually export the whole hausman output (to a table). TY :)